# Running multiple docker-compose.yml with port overlap

Tags: docker, containers

I'm trying to do integration tests with docker-compose with multiple projects coming into build. I have the following questions:

1) How can i run multiple docker-compose mini infrastructures with port overlap and still allow these compose networks to talk to each other?

2) How can I lock down the server so arbitrary docker-compose.yml don't actually expose or open ports on the server and are merely virtual with in its own space?

3) can I run arbitrary image builds from dockerfile without security issues,... like mounting a volume you're not supposed to?